# Como podria saber que metodo esta invocando un pointcut en aspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

Buenas dias recien estoy aprendiendo aspectJ.

```
public class Bank {

   
    public static void createUser(){
        String nombre = readConsole("Nombre :");
        int id = Integer.valueOf(readConsole("Id: "));
        double money = Double.valueOf(readConsole("Dinero: "));
        users.add(new User(users.size(),nombre,id,money));
    }

    public static void moneyMakeTransaction(){
        int id = Integer.valueOf(readConsole("Key: "));
        double money = Double.valueOf(readConsole("Dinero a depositar: "));
        users.get(id-1).setMoney(users.get(id-1).getMoney() + money);
    }
    public static void moneyWithdrawal(){
        int id = Integer.valueOf(readConsole("Key: "));
        double money = Double.valueOf(readConsole("Dinero a retirar: "));
        users.get(id-1).setMoney(users.get(id-1).getMoney() - money);
    }
```

En esta clase tengo dos metodos uno para retiro de dinero llamado `moneyMakeTransaction` y otro para retiro `moneyWithdrawal`.

```
public aspect Logger {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    pointcut money():execution(void *money*(..));
    pointcut user(): execution(void *create*(..));

    after(): money(){
        writeFile("Deposito realizado" + cal.getTime());
    }
    
    after(): money() {
        writeFile("Retiro realizado" + cal.getTime());
    }
```

El pointcut captura cada vez que se llama a uno de los dos métodos ya sea "hacer transacción" o "hacer retiro" pero me gustaria saber como obtener que metodo esta llamando el usuario en ese momento, ya que necesito conocer si mi usuario esta realizando un deposito o un retiro.